# Foreach without first row

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

I use this code

```
<li th:each="r : ${data}">...</li>
```

to get list of elements.
Can I get a list without first row. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can associate a Stat variable to the th:each loop -

```
<li th:each="r,rStat : ${data}" th:if="${rStat.count} &gt; 1">
...
</li>
```

This has a associated count variable so you can exclude the first row using the construct above

[Link](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#iteration-basics)